# Fast convert datetime string to seconds (Python3)

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

Trying to convert a **huge amount** of records (time series) to int like this:

```
seconds_time = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(parts[0], '%Y%m%d %H%M%S')))
```

Unfortunately, this is the code's bottle neck (time-consuming increases by factor of about **20**). Any suggestions to improve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Using multiprocessing. But still, this is the weakest point of the code...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually there's a way to drastically reduce parsing time.

```
import time

start = time.time()

nb_loops = 1000000
time_string = "20170101 201456"
for i in range(nb_loops):
    seconds_time = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(time_string, '%Y%m%d %H%M%S')))
print(time.time()-start)
```

that first loop runs in 12 seconds. Not very good I admit.

*But*, since your format is simple, why not use integer conversion with slicing in a list comprehension (and add 0 for the missing fields like milliseconds, ...) and pass the result to `mktime`.

```
start = time.time()

for i in range(nb_loops):
    seconds_time = time.mktime(tuple([int(time_string[s:e]) for s,e in ((0,4),(4,6),(6,8),(9,11),(11,13),(13,15))]+[0,0,0]))
print(time.time()-start)
```

that runs in 3 seconds (saves the parsing of the `'%Y%m%d %H%M%S'` format string, which seems to take a while).

Using compiled regular expressions is slightly faster:

```
import re
r = re.compile("(....)(..)(..) (..)(..)(..)")
start = time.time()

for i in range(nb_loops):
    seconds_time = time.mktime(tuple(map(int,r.match(time_string).groups()))+(0,0,0))
print(time.time()-start)
```

results:

```
basic 14.41410493850708
string slicing 3.1356000900268555
regex 2.8703999519348145
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot, really much faster!

Comment: Done ;) Thanks again